# Check all values in string[] for length?

Tags: c#, .net

I have an `string[]` with some values. I would like to check the length of every string. Actually I just want to be sure that none of them got a length over 20 chars. Is there a fast way?

Comment: how big is your string[] going to be?  if you aren't dealing with an array that is thousands in size... probably doesn't matter too much which approach you take for fastest performance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `Enumberable.Any` method documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.any.aspx) to quickly check if there is an item exceeding 20 characters in your array.

```
array.Any(x => x.Length > 20)
```

Comment: That is looking nice. But I would try to get the strings that are > 20, I could not do it with linq right? Just asking, not that important.

Comment: Sure you could, use `Where(x=>x.Length>20)`!

Comment: @silla Sure you could; just use `Where` if you want to actually get them all

Comment: Anyway, if any of the strings in `array` is `null`, you might get an exception. If you want to accept that situation (i.e. don't want the exception), use `x => x != null && x.Length > 20` instead.

Comment: You can also coalesce with an empty enumerable to tolerate a null array reference: `(array ?? Enumerable.Empty<string>()).Any(x=>x.Length > 20);` will return false if array is null because it will instead use the zero-length enumerable (which has no elements meeting the criteria because it has no elements at all).

Comment: @KeithS That handles the case where the array is null, not one of the elements in the array being null.

Comment: But if you really like null coalescing, there's also the possibility `x => (x ?? "").Length > 20`.

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var s in strings)
{
    if (s.Length > 20)
    {
        // found a string with length over 20 characters
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
string[] youtStringArray= new string[] {"Michigan", "NewYork", "Florida"};
foreach(var item in youtStringArray)
{
  if(item.Length>20)
  {
    //do some thing , may be substring  to first 20 ?
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
if (array.Count(o => o.Length > 20) > 0)
{
// Do something
}
```