# Check All Values for Items in String List Simultaneously

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have a program that highlights the name of a server whenever there is a "signal" coming from it. I have a list of values containing the server signals and it gets updated every second. I want to be able to check the entire list all at once, prior to the next "tick", and then return the servers that have signals on them at that moment so that I can highlight them.

I have the following code which determines which server has the MOST signals and also which has the LONGEST amount of time the signal has been there. You'd think what I'm trying to do would be simpler than this but for some reason I'm lost. Here's that code (which works perfectly)-

```
var mostSignals = serverInfo.Aggregate(emptyServer, (s1, s2) =>
{
    var s1Signals = int.Parse(s1?.Signals ?? "0");
    var s2Signals = int.Parse(s2?.Signals ?? "0");
    return s1Signals < s2Signals ? s2 : s1;
});

var longestHold = serverInfo.Aggregate(emptyServer, (s1, s2) =>
{
    var s1Hold = TimeSpan.Parse(s1?.LongestHold ?? "00:00");
    var s2Hold = TimeSpan.Parse(s2?.LongestHold ?? "00:00");
    return s1Hold < s2Hold ? s2 : s1;
});
```

After looking through some articles I found one that seemed like the right path to go down but either I'm doing something wrong or it's not what I think it is-
[Check all values in string[] for length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12356935/check-all-values-in-string-for-length)

Current code that I have for this-

```
var anySignals = serverInfo.Any(x => x.Signals != "0");
```

But from what I can gather that will just return true or false if any of the servers have signals on them.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Sorry, it was suggested and I just clicked it without thinking.

Comment: @YacoubMassad The question is in the title basically. I'm trying to check all of a list element's values at once.

Comment: I think you want `Where` instead of `Any`.

Comment: But it is not clear. What exactly do you want to check?

Comment: Also, what do you mean "at once"? Are there multiple threads involved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is:

```
var anySignals = serverInfo.Where(x => x.Signals != "0");
```

This will return all the servers where the `Signals` is not equal to the string "0".

You can then loop over all of results highlighting the name as required.